# Зачем в java нужен protected конструктор

Tags: java

Зачем в java нужен protected конструктор?

Comment: Может для реализации базового класса синглтона?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`protected` конструктор позволяет запретить создание экземпляра базового  класса. В производных классах этот конструктор будет доступен, а стало быть, можно будет создавать потомков.

Данный подход применим во многих ООП языках, не только в [java](/questions/tagged/java).

Comment: насколько я понимаю, не совсем _позволяет запретить создание экземпляра базового класса_, а создавать экземпляр базового класса напрямую именно этим конструктором. Класс вполне может иметь статическую функцию внутри, которой бы вызывался этот protected конструктор, либо вызывать этот конструктор из другого, публичного конструктора

Comment: А чем этот подход отличается от объявления класса абстракным?

Comment: @MaxArt, тем, что экземпляр класса все еще можно создать, экземпляр абстрактного класса - нельзя

Comment: Было бы круто увидеть в ответе пару примеров того как можно это применить)

Comment: А экземпляр класса с protected конструктором получается все таки можно создавать в классах того же пакета?

Comment: @MaxArt, протектед влияет только на то, что нельзя сделать `new MyClass()` - нигде вне класса или наследников, если конструктор без параметров протектед

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, я там подредактировал уже сообщение :-)

Comment: @Grundy все равно `нельзя сделать new MyClass() - нигде вне класса или наследников, если конструктор без параметров протектед` не согласуется с тем, что `можно создать` ...или я не улавливаю

Comment: @АлексейШиманский, внутри функции класса - можно вызвать, соответственно и создать, внутри наследника можно вызвать и соответственно создать, просто так внутри какого-то другого класса через `new` создать нельзя

Comment: Почему нельзя, если класс в котором создаем объект с protected конструктором находится в том же пакете, то можно или я не прав?

Comment: @MaxArt, таки попробуй :-)

Comment: Ну так я и попробовал)) Получается что в своем пакете можно создавать, а в стороннем уже нет. Я склоняюсь к мнению, что класс все таки нельзя создавать явно в рамках других пакетов, кроме ситуации с явным наследованием. А в текущем пакете создание не запрещено. Поэтому и возник вопрос.

Answer (score 6):

protected конструктор нужен для вызова его из наследников, но сокрытия от доступа извне.
Отличный пример - *protected* конструктор класса *Throwable*.

```
Throwable(String message, Throwable cause, boolean enableSuppression, boolean writableStackTrace)
```

Последний параметр указывает, нужно ли писать стектрейс (что является очень затратной операцией). Можно наследоваться от *Throwable* и, вызывая этот конструктор родителя, получать очень легковесные "сигнальные" исключения.

Comment: мне кажется или в первом предложении пропущены слова _не только_ после "нужен" и _и для_ после "но"?

Comment: Я всё же склонен считать, что вам кажется. Предложение принимает немного другой окрас.

Comment: да, тяжеловатая фраза получилась :)