# Создание объекта абстрактного класса

Tags: java, классы

Вопрос навеян темой [Зачем в java нужен protected конструктор](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540525/%D0%97%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%B2-java-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD-protected-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80)

Хотел в качестве применения protected конструктора привести класс java.util.Calendar. Но для начала посмотрел в исходники и, с удивлением, обнаружил, что этот класс является абстрактным.
Всегда считал, что нельзя создать экземпляр абстрактного класса. Но получить объект класса Calendar можно с помощью

```
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
```

В чем же тогда суть запрета создавать экземпляр абстрактного класса? Я просто не могу написать в коде new Calendar()? А через какие-то другие методы могу спокойно получить экземпляр такого класса? То есть верно ли утверждение, что "если класс является абстрактным, то его конструктор по умолчанию является protected"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если ты заглянешь в реализацию getInstance, то увидишь, что этот метод вызывает другой статичный метод createCalendar, а уже он создает не объекты абстрактного класса Calendar, а объекты наследников этого класса, например BuddhistCalendar. Так как BuddhistCalendar наследует Calendar, то позволяется неявное приведение к этому типу.

Answer (score 3):

Давайте проведём различие между заявленным и реальным типом объекта. Ссылка, которая у вас есть, ссылается на заявленный тип, тип, известный при компиляции. А вот реальный тип объекта при этом может быть любым производным от заявленного типа.

Например, если у вас есть `List<String> l`, то реальный объект по ссылке может быть, например, типа `ArrayList<String>`.

Теперь назад, к теме вопроса. Вы таки не можете иметь экземпляр с *реальным* типом, соответствующим абстрактному классу. Потому что такой объект просто нельзя сконструировать. А вот *заявленный* тип `Calendar` означает, что реально там или `Calendar` (что невозможно, т. к. он абстрактный), или любой производный от него тип.

[Проверим](http://ideone.com/usPPEX):

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println(c);
```

Получаем вывод (в моём случае) `java.util.GregorianCalendar[...` — экземпляр производного типа.

---

Суть запрета на создание абстрактного класса заключается в том, что этот класс *не окончен*, и должен быть окончен в порождённых классах. Например, в нём отсутствуют какие-то методы. Раз этот класс не готов к использованию, то и создавать его нельзя. А вот законченные, готовые к использованию порождённые классы можно инстанциировать.