# Что с календарем?

Tags: java, android, calendar

У меня есть переменная календаря и число `long` которое соответствует дате в миллисекундах. Я пытаюсь установить в переменную календаря эту дату.

В описании переменных, до `onCreate` объявлено `Calendar calendar_1;`
затем в `onCreate` я достаю сохраненное число и пытаюсь установить его в дату:

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
calendar_1.setTimeInMillis(prefs.getLong(pref_cal_1, 0));
```

Но вылетает ошибка, мол я пытаюсь применить метод `.setTimeInMillis` на `null object`

Если написать вот так:

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
calendar_1 = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar_1.setTimeInMillis(prefs.getLong(pref_cal_1, 0));
```

то все работает. Никак не могу понять суть проблемы, разве `getInstance` не устанавливает текущее значение? он же не нужен тут если я хочу свою дату установить.

Comment: getInstance() не только устанавливает текущее время, но и создает экземпляр объекта с которым в последствии можно работать

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Но вылетает ошибка, мол я пытаюсь применить метод `.setTimeInMillis` на
>   `null object`

В этом и есть суть проблемы - вы не инициализировали объект `calendar_1`. Для этого всегда требуется вызывать метод `Calendar.getInstance()`

---

*P.S. [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/540591/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%8A%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%B0%D0%B1%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B0) об этом написано*